# App keeps crashing at the @Override point

Tags: java, android, crash, overriding

I am in the process of making my first android app.
i am currently trying to get a custom adapter to work.

This is the code:

CustomAdapter class:

```
class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
//    List <Note> notesR = new ArrayList<Note>();
ArrayList<Note> notesR;

public CustomListAdapter (List notes) {
    // mContext = context;
//       notesR =  = notes;



    notesR = new ArrayList<Note>(3);
    notesR.add(new Note("Hello", "bye", new Date()));
    notesR.add(new Note("Hello", "bye", new Date()));
    notesR.add(new Note("Hello", "bye", new Date()));
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return notesR.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return notesR.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;

}

// This method is called to draw each row of the list
@Override
public View getView(int index, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;

    if (vi == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

    }

    final Note noteModel = notesR.get(index);

    TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date);
    date.setText("" + noteModel.getDate());
    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(noteModel.getTitle());
    TextView content = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.content);
    content.setText(noteModel.getNote());
    // here you inflate the layout you want for the row
    final View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list, null);



    return view;
```

List notes class:

```
public class ListNotesActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =     (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    notes.remove(info.position);
    populateList();
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo  menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        return;
    }
    Serializable extra = data.getSerializableExtra("Note");
    if (extra != null){

        Note newNote = (Note)extra;
        if (editingNoteId > -1){

            notes.set(editingNoteId, newNote);
            editingNoteId = -1;
        }
        else {

            notes.add(newNote);
        };
        populateList();
    }

}



private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
private ListView notesListView;
private int editingNoteId = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_notes);
    notesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.notesListView);

    notesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int itemNumber, long id) {

            Intent editNoteIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditNotesActivity.class);
            editNoteIntent.putExtra("Note", notes.get(itemNumber));
            editingNoteId = itemNumber;
            startActivityForResult(editNoteIntent, 1);


        }
    });

    registerForContextMenu(notesListView);

    notes.add(new Note("1 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("2 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("3 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("4 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("5 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("6 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("7 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("8 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));

    populateList();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_notes, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //notes.add(new Note("Added note", "blah", new Date()));
    //populateList();

    Intent editNoteIntent = new Intent (this, EditNotesActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(editNoteIntent, 1);


    return true;


}




// Populate Method

// Populate Method
private void populateList() {

    CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(notes);
     notesListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    //CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    //notesListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

I have been trying to get the apapter to work with dummy data to start with, but it still keeps crashing.

i have been trying to find the source of the problem with break points,
If i put a creak point just before the first @Overrride, it runs fine up till there, but as soon as i let it run thru to the @Override it crashes.
I tried removing the first override, and the code then ran fine, up till the next override, where it crashed again.

I have been trying to get this working all day, n i even sent it to my farther who is C# dev, and he didnt know either.

If anyone could tell me exactly whats causing this i would be very grateful.

I have a example i downloaded, which uses very similar code to mine, and it runs fine. this is the code from the example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;

public CustomAdapter() {
listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>(5);
listArray.add(new DataModel("Title1", "Java", new Date()));
listArray.add(new DataModel("name2",  "Python", new Date()));
listArray.add(new DataModel("name3",  "Django", new Date()));
listArray.add(new DataModel("name4",  "Groovy", new Date()));
listArray.add(new DataModel("name5", "Maven", new Date()));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return listArray.size();    // total number of elements in the list

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
return listArray.get(i);    // single item in the list
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
return i;                   // index number
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
}

final DataModel dataModel = listArray.get(index);

TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(dataModel.getTitle());

TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
content.setText(dataModel.getContent());

TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
date.setText("" + dataModel.getDate());


return view;
```

EDIT 1:

> LogCat (i filtered it for just my app):
>
> 06-12 15:26:46.359    8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui
>   D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI 06-12 15:26:46.399
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     W/ActivityThread: Application
>   com.fishingfon.notetakerui is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
>   06-12 15:26:46.409    8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui
>   I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk 06-12 15:26:46.419
>   8851-8856/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/dalvikvm: Debugger is
>   active 06-12 15:26:46.614    8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui
>   I/System.out: Debugger has connected 06-12 15:26:46.614
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/System.out: waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 06-12 15:26:46.814
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/System.out: waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 06-12 15:26:47.014
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/System.out: waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 06-12 15:26:47.214
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/System.out: waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 06-12 15:26:47.289
>   2137-2137/com.google.android.youtube     D/YouTube MDX: Recieved
>   intent android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF 06-12 15:26:47.414
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/System.out: waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 06-12 15:26:47.614
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/System.out: waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 06-12 15:26:47.814
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/System.out: debugger has
>   settled (1315) 06-12 15:26:48.149
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM 06-12 15:26:48.149    8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui
>   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40f4d930) 06-12 15:26:48.169
>   8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fishingfon.notetakerui/com.fishingfon.notetakerui.ListNotesActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5231)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.fishingfon.notetakerui.ListNotesActivity.populateList(ListNotesActivity.java:145)
>           at com.fishingfon.notetakerui.ListNotesActivity.onCreate(ListNotesActivity.java:110)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5110)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>           ... 11 more 06-12 15:26:48.209    8851-8851/com.fishingfon.notetakerui     I/Process: Sending signal.
>   PID: 8851 SIG: 9

EDIT 2:

new adapter code:

```
class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
//    List <Note> notesR = new ArrayList<Note>();
ArrayList<Note> notesR;

public CustomListAdapter (Context context, Object notes) {
     mContext = context;
//       notesR =  = notes;



    notesR = new ArrayList<Note>(3);
    notesR.add(new Note("Hello", "bye", new Date()));
    notesR.add(new Note("Hello", "bye", new Date()));
    notesR.add(new Note("Hello", "bye", new Date()));
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return notesR.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return notesR.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;

}

// This method is called to draw each row of the list
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;

    if (vi == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
       // inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        vi = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list, null);

    }

    final Note noteModel = notesR.get(position);

    TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date);
    date.setText("" + noteModel.getDate());
    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(noteModel.getTitle());
    TextView content = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.content);
    content.setText(noteModel.getNote());


    return vi;
```

Thanks in advance
Cheers
Corey

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: i guess you should remove this `final View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list, null);` and return `vi` instead in `getView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here this code not required

```
final View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list, null);
return view;
```

just add this instead of above

```
return vi;
```

in getView() of CustomListAdapter

**EDIT**

```
public CustomListAdapter (Context context, int id, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
   super(context,id,notes);
   mContext = context;
   notesR =  = notes;
}
```

in Activity

```
CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, notes);
notesListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: Hi, I have done what you said, but it still keeps crashing at the overrides. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?. i am still very new to java. Thanks, Cheers Corey

Comment: Hi, i will add the logcat to my original post. and i am getting the error in the CustomListAdapter i posted above, at each override. Thanks, Corey

Comment: Show me this line ListNotesActivity.java:145.

Comment: Hi, the line from that logcat entry is:             notesListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
I posted the complete populateList method above if you need the rest of the code (its at the end of the ListNotesActivity). Thanks, Corey

Comment: PS: i have just tried moving:                             CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter();
notesListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);                                 from the populate method, to the onCreate method, and removed the "notes" parameter (its just using dummy data), and it runs fine, and displays the dummy data. but as soon as i put it in the populatelist method, it force closes as soon as it hits the "Override" and .getSize code. Does anyone know why it would be doing that when its in the populate method?. Thanks, Corey

Comment: Ps (again): i just tried commenting out all the populatelist method calls, and then un commenting them oneat a time to see which is causing the force close, and it turns out its the last call that causes it to force close, but i cant seem to figure out why. Corey

Comment: You have to pass Context to the adapter like this CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, data); try like this it will work.let me know the result.

Comment: Hi, I have done what you said, and i think i changed the code inside the adapter correctly to use the context, but it still force closes on the last populatelist call!. i have added the New Adapter code to my original post. i had originaly made the adapter with the context parameter, but then i commented it out well i tried to debug something else. Thanks for all your help, Cheers

Comment: try my edited answer this will work properly, otherwise in your code have problems .

Comment: Hi, i tried what you posted, but it still crashes when called from populatelist method, altho if i just move the code from the populatelist method to the oncreate method, it doesnt crash. thanks for your help, Cheers, Corey